# If my app has to work in a cluster, will using flash[] cause issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If my app has to work in a cluster, will using flash[] cause issues?

From what I understand, it uses sessions?

I have set my sessions to be 'cookie_store', so does that solve the potential issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Using the cookie store offloads all the session data to the client to be passed along in the request.